# parity stable build from source

Tags: parity

How can I build [parity](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/releases) as a stable version from source?

```
git clone https://github.com/paritytech/parity
cd parity
cargo build --release
```

gives me

`version Parity/v1.9.0-unstable-51e6e0b4b-20171230/x86_64-linux-gnu/r‌​ustc1.22.1`

which is unstable and

```
git checkout tags/v1.7.11
```

gives me this version:

```
version Parity/v1.7.11-unstable-a5ed4cfc4-20171228/x86_64-linux-gnu/‌​rustc1.22.1
```

which is unstable as well. How can I build the stable version from source (latest should be 1.7.11)

Answer (score 1):

Version `v1.7.11` was actually stable. `-unstable` part of the name is a bug and we've recently [fixed it](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/pull/7426#issuecomment-354750953). Version `v1.7.12` should display the version properly.

Answer (score 0):

`unstable` just says that the version was compiled from source. :)

To get a meaningful string, compile parity with the additional flag `--features final`